# How to solve this question asked in premium coding contest?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy

Could someone guide me on how to solve this programming question? It seems something like DP problem which I couldn't find answer for.

Question:

> There are ‘n’ ads. Each ad has an effectiveness value associated with
>   it which is given in an array of size ‘n’ in the format [v1, v2, …,
>   vn], where ‘v1’ is the effectiveness value of the first ad, ‘v2’ is
>   the effectiveness value of the second ad, and so on. The show in which
>   these ads will be shown is ‘m’ length long (starting from 0 till m),
>   and the time when the ads can be shown is given in the format [(a1,
>   b1), (a2, b2), …, (an, bn)], where ith tuple in the array denotes the
>   timing of the ith ad in the format (start_time, end_time). Note that
>   any ‘ai’ and ‘bi’ cannot be smaller than 0 and cannot be larger than
>   ‘m’. When you choose to show an ad, you cannot show another ad within
>   4 minutes of it’s end. So if you select to show the ad having timings
>   as (2, 4), then you cannot show another ad before 9, hence next ad
>   cannot be (8, 10), but it can be (9, 12). You have to select the ads
>   to show to the audience such that you maximize the sum of the
>   effectiveness values of the ads, given the above constraints. For
>   example, if ‘m’ is 20, and the timings of the ads are [(2, 3), (6, 9),
>   (10, 12), (12, 13), (14, 17)] and the effectiveness values are [3, 9,
>   10, 6, 7], then you can show ad 2 and ad 5 (one-based-indexing) and
>   have an effectiveness value of 16, which is the maximum you can get
>   given the constraints.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem? Can you show us your ideas or approaches?

Comment: I am trying to create an optimal sub-structure property with this problem. which, I couldn't. So, I'm asking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to the following, let's consider 1d segments that can be described as (start_i, end_i, value_i).

Let S = array of available 1d segments

What we want is to find the non-intersecting segments that sum to the maximum possible value and fit in the interval [0, m] ( show length )

Let DP[x] = best achievable value to cover the segment [0, x] with a subset of the available 1d segments.

The recurrence relation is, given an element (s_i, e_i, v_i) we can select it or not.

DP[e_i] = DP[e_i - 1]

DP[e_i] = max( DP[e_i], DP[s_i - 1] + v_i )

```
dp[0] = 0;
// sort the events by increasing e_i, because
// we want to process first the events that finish earlier

for( int END = 1; END <= m; ++END)
{
    dp[end] = dp[end - 1];
    for( each ELEMENT(s_i, e_i, v_u) with (e_i == END) )
    {
        dp[end] = max( dp[end], dp[s_i - 1] + v_i ) 
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the fact that we can show another ad only if there is a 4 min gap?